# Count for each row on mysql

Tags: mysql

i have this query:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb_pinturas WHERE c.catId= 4) AS desejo,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb_pinturas WHERE c.catId= 2) AS europa,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb_pinturas WHERE c.catId= 6) AS futebol,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb_pinturas WHERE c.catId= 8) AS jazz,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb_pinturas WHERE c.catId= 3) AS praia,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb_pinturas WHERE c.catId= 1) AS sp,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb_pinturas WHERE c.catId= 7) AS tamta,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb_pinturas WHERE c.catId= 5) AS velocidade,
    c.catNome AS nome, 
    c.catSlug AS slug, 
    c.catId AS id  
FROM aux_categoria c 
LEFT JOIN tb_pinturas p ON(c.catId = p.catId)
GROUP BY c.catid    ORDER BY c.catNome;
```

and i want to make just one column for each count. What should i do?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here.. you seem to have one column for each already.

Comment: i want to bring the name, id and count column, just 3 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
SELECT 
    c.catNome AS nome, 
    c.catId AS id,
    count(p.catId) as the_count  
FROM aux_categoria c 
LEFT JOIN tb_pinturas p ON(c.catId = p.catId)
GROUP BY c.catNome,c.catid    
ORDER BY c.catNome
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need each subquery. You can use `SUM()` to count the values return by the boolean expression.

```
SELECT  SUM(c.catId = 4) AS desejo,
        SUM(c.catId = 2) AS europa,
        SUM(c.catId = 6) AS futebol,
        SUM(c.catId = 8) AS jazz,
        SUM(c.catId = 3) AS praia,
        SUM(c.catId = 1) AS sp,
        SUM(c.catId = 7) AS tamta,
        SUM(c.catId = 5) AS velocidade,
        c.catNome AS nome, 
        c.catSlug AS slug, 
        c.catId AS id  
FROM    aux_categoria c 
        LEFT JOIN tb_pinturas p 
            ON c.catId = p.catId
GROUP   BY  c.catid,
            c.catNome, 
            c.catSlu  
ORDER   BY  c.catNome
```

Comment: thats it, but how query for one column group by catNome?